# Conditional formatting: How to shade a specific number of cells on the row after I input certain phase in a certain cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I would like to enter a certain phase in a certain cell, says ABC in C2, then E2, H2, J2 and K2 will be change to certain color. Thank you in advance!

I have been searching and reading posts about conditional formatting for two days, perhaps my English hinders me from knowing the right keywords to search for the right answer. Please see the attached illustrating the desired result.   Thank you!

[image: The desired result when I type in ABC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the cells you want to format (E2,H2,J2,K2) individually using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click. Then go to Conditional Formatting | New rule | Use a formula ... and enter:-

```
=$C2="ABC"
```

and choose the fill colour you want to use.

This will also match "abc". If you only want to match "ABC", use instead:-

```
=EXACT($C2,"ABC")
```